# server.bash is not a valid win32 application

Tags: bash, websocket, server

I'm trying to host a simple (demo) [websocketd](http://websocketd.com) server. Basically, it listens to incoming websocket connections and routes them towards my server. However, when I run the `websocketd --port=8069 server.bash` (In the correct directory, websocketd running as admin) I get the following error when trying to connect to `ws://localhost:8069`:

```
Could not launch process .\server.bash (fork/exec .\server.bash: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.)
```

I've looked into `netstat` and the 8069 IS listening for incoming connections.
I've also tried running a python server (I have it installed) but I get the same error

//System Info:
I'm running x64 windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Description of websocketd from the url you provided

> It takes care of handling the WebSocket connections,
>   launching your programs to handle the WebSockets, ....

So basically websocketd is trying to execute `server.bash` which doesn't work because windows doesn't recognize this file as executable.
This script was probably meant to be run on linux in the first place however if you have installed bash already on windows u can try running it by replacing

```
websocketd --port=8069 server.bash
```

with

```
websocketd --port=8069 bash server.bash
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the "bash" there. Running `./websocketd --port=8069 bash server.bash' in Git Bash proved to be the sollution